# How to customize Subscribe2 button appearance in WordPress?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, blogs, subscribe2

I'm very new to WordPress and have no PHP or CSS experience...

I'm want to use [Subscribe2](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/subscribe2/) plugin in my blog, together with [iNove](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/inove) theme. When I add the widget, the Subscribe/Unsubscribe buttons are rendered in the "classic" way, which makes the page quite ugly (the blog is at: http://www.adlerr.com)

[image]

How can I customize the appearance of the buttons? I'm ready to write some PHP/CSS if I get proper instructions...

The code outputting the buttons is here:

```
$this->form = "<form method=\"post\" action=\"\"><p>" . __('Your email:', 'subscribe2') 
. "<input type=\"text\" name=\"email\" value=\"" . __('Enter email address...', 
'subscribe2') . "\" size=\"20\" onfocus=\"if (this.value == '" . __('Enter email     
address...', 'subscribe2') . "') {this.value = '';}\" onblur=\"if (this.value == '')     
{this.value = '" . __('Enter email address...', 'subscribe2') . "';}\" /></p><p><input 
type=\"submit\" class=\"button\" name=\"subscribe\" value=\"" . __('Subscribe', 
'subscribe2') . "\" />&nbsp;<input type=\"submit\" class=\"button\" name=\"unsubscribe\" 
value=\"" . __('Unsubscribe', 'subscribe2') . "\" /></p></form>\r\n";
```

And there are buttons will proper stying [here](http://www.adlerr.com/2009/08/16/welcome/#respond): bottom right, the "Submit Comment" button, that is of class "button":

[image]

The code generating the Submit Comment button is:

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" class="button" tabindex="5" 
value="<?php _e('Submit Comment', 'inove'); ?>" />
```

What should I do to make the Subscribe/Unsubscribe buttons look like the "Submit Comment" button?

Your help is much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the unstyled and styled buttons is that the unstyled buttons don't have an attribute of class="button".

You should be able to log into WP, click plugins, click edit on the Subscribe2 plugin and find where the input type=submit buttons are and add a class="button" to them.

```
<input type="submit" class="button" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe"/>
<input type="submit" class="button" value="Unsubscribe" name="unsubscribe"/>
```

**Edit:** In your css file, you will want to create a class called button:

```
.button {
  background-color: #e0ffff;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

You'll need to change/add these values to something that suits you. You can find out more about [css at w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/default.asp). You will probably want to look at background, text, font, and box model.

Alright, I got it this time!

Change line 949 in style.css to this:

```
#submitbox #submit, .button {
```

Change line 960 in style.css to this:

```
#submitbox #submit:hover, .button:hover {
```

Comment: Button definitions appear tens of times in the plugin's PHP code. Most of them include either class="button-primary" or class="button-secondary". There was button definition without class definition, I added class="button" to it but it didn't change the appearance.

Comment: Can you show me a page on your blog that has correctly styled buttons? I was going off of the button styling that the iNove theme had.

Comment: I've put 3 buttons at the About page, of classes "button", "button-primary" and "button-secondary". All look the same. What's wrong?

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood. I thought there were buttons on the iNove theme that you liked and weren't showing up on your plugin. I will edit my answer.